# Phalcon Session

Tags: session, phalcon

I have set my session, however it is not being seen on the other pages.

within the loginController, the login function has:

```
  $session->set('auth', $user->id);
```

I want when the person log in, it redirects to the index page, but a check needs to be done. However when I tried the below code, it throws an error that session was not defined.

```
  if ($session->has("auth")) { 
  //Retrieve its value 
  $name = $session->get("auth"); 
  echo("   ".$name); 
  exit;
  }
```

I would like when the session is set from the login controller, that the session variable is seen and can be checked is a session was infact set or not. If it is set, show the page. If it was not set, redirect to login.

Comment: Has a session started, like `$session->start()`? Check https://docs.phalcon.io/5.0/en/tutorial-vokuro Is a very good example of what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks Arthur, I figured it out.  I created the session in the loginController, and added the correct code to the services.php for 'session'; I am finding phalcon 4 superhard to find information on. I have yet another issue now. You had helped me setup the phalcon version and php versions to be compatible and Im sure that I had scaffolded the users table. Now when I am trying to rescaffold, its is telling me   Error: Adapter Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql is not supported

Comment: Glad that it works now. Please share your code for the session and database services. As for documentation, Phalcon Docs is the main resource and you can explore this book that was written for 3.4 but it's pretty much useful for 4.0: https://www.packtpub.com/product/phalcon-cookbook/9781784396886